# Javascript files does not load in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I included my external Javascript files in my index.html file, and for whatever reason it doesn't load, and no error is thrown.

```
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share your entire HTML code? Are you even using React? Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, I'm using React.

However, I imported these js files in my index.html. I don't know if there's an alternative, or if it's completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I used the react-script-tag library.

I created a component that used the react-script-tag to include all the js files, and imported them in other components that needs them.